# Lazy loading data a la Skeleton Screens. Is it possible?

Tags: sql, database, performance, database-design, information-retrieval

I've been reading the article [The Vietnam of Computer Science](http://blogs.tedneward.com/post/the-vietnam-of-computer-science/) by Ted Neward. Although there's much I don't understand, or have not fully grasped, I was struck by a thought while reading this paragraph.

> **The Partial-Object Problem and the Load-Time Paradox**
>
> It has long been known that network traversal, such as that done when making a traditional SQL request, takes a significant amount of time to process. ... This cost is clearly non-trivial, so as a result, developers look for ways to minimize this cost by optimizing the number of round trips and data retrieved.
>
> In SQL, this optimization is achieved by carefully structuring the SQL request, making sure to retrieve only the columns and/or tables desired, rather than entire tables or sets of tables. For example, when constructing a traditional drill-down user interface, the developer presents a summary display of all the records from which the user can select one, and once selected, the developer then displays the complete set of data for that particular record. Given that we wish to do a drill-down of the Persons relational type described earlier, for example, the two queries to do so would be, in order (assuming the first one is selected):

```
SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM person;


SELECT * FROM person WHERE id = 1;
```

> In particular, take notice that only the data desired at each stage of the process is retrieved–in the first query, the necessary summary information and identifier (for the subsequent query, in case first and last name wouldn’t be sufficient to identify the person directly), and in the second, the remainder of the data to display. ... This notion of being able to return a part of a table (though still in relational form, which is important for reasons of closure, described above) is fundamental to the ability to optimize these queries this way–most queries will, in fact, only require a portion of the complete relation.

---

### Skeleton Screens

Skeleton Screens are a relatively new UI design concept introduced in 2013 by Luke Wrobleski [in this paper](https://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1797). It encourages avoiding spinners to indicate loading and to instead gradually build UI elements, during load time, which makes the user feel as if things are quickly progressing and progress is being made, even if it's, in fact, slower than than when using a traditional loading indicator.

[image: Skeleton Screen in use in the Microsoft Teams chat app]

Here is a Skeleton Screen in use in the Microsoft Teams chat app. It displays this while waiting for stored chat logs to arrive from the database.

---

### Utilizing Skeleton Screen Style Data Loading as a Paradigm for Data Retrieval

While Neward's paper is focusing on Object Relational Mappers, I had this thought about structuring data retrieval.

The paragraph quoted above indicates a struggle with querying too much data at one time, increasing data retrieval times until all the indicated data is gathered. What if, similar to Neward's SQL example above, smaller chunks of data were retrieved, as necessary, and loaded piecemeal into the application?

This would necessitate a fundamental shift in database querying logic, I think. It would obviously be a ridiculous suggestion to have this implemented in application code. To have your everyday developer write a multi-layered retrieval scheme to retrieve a single object would be insane. Rather, there would need to be some sort of built-in method whereby the developer can indicate which properties are considered to be required (username, Id, permissions, roles, etc...) which *must* be retrieved fully before moving forward, and which properties are ancillary. After all, many app users navigate through an application faster than all the data can populate, if they are familiar with the application and just need to navigate to a certain page. All they need is *enough* data to be loaded, which is the point of this scheme.

On the database side, there would probably a series of smaller retrievals, rather than a large one. I know this is probably more expensive, although I'm not certain of the technicalities, and while database performance may suffer, application performance might improve, at least as perceived by the user.

---

### Conclusion

Imagine pulling up your Instagram and having the first series of photos (the ones you can see) load, twice as quickly as before. Photos are likely your first priority. It wouldn't matter if your username, notification indicator, and profile picture takes a few extra seconds to populate, since you have already been fed your expected data and have begun consuming as a user. Contrast that with having structural data loaded first. Nobody cares about seeing their username or the company logo load. They want to see content.

I don't know if this is a terrible idea or something that has already been considered, but I'd love to get some feedback on it.

What do you think?

Is it possible, from a technical standpoint?

Comment: `It would obviously be a ridiculous suggestion to have this implemented in application code.'`  I think just the opposite, sorry.  If you want to load some things quickly and other things can be slower, then it's up to you to design an application that does just that.  I think the best you could ask for is an application that is able to do some of this design for you.  SSRS is an example of a product that does basically what you describe already regarding drill-down reporting and data retrieval.  The report designer abtracts (to some extent) the staggered data retrieval.

Comment: Further, products like Instagram don't really work the way you describe.  In order to even open Instagram you must already have entered (or have stored) your username and password.  This information is not retrieved -- it is already available to the application.  Other things like a company logo can be cached and synced, which essentially is part of the "skeleton screen" you describe.

Comment: Re: Instagram. You are correct, I meant that as an extremely simplified example.

Comment: Sure, there would need to be some responsibility on the part of the application developer, but I feel like the key element in this idea is A) Choosing which element is primary and which is secondary (which would be the dev responsibility) and B) separating out those requests to the database in a manner that prioritizes the elements of primary importance.